# Search for a value inside a document [MongoDB]

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I'm trying to find a value inside a document in **MongoDB**, coded in **JAVA**, I'll give an example:

Main document:

```
date: 12.2
rate: 9
people:
   1:George
   2:Candice
   3: James
   4: John
   x:
   x+1:
```

> This is really just in theory, the date and rate don't matter it's
>   just an example.

Let's say I have the people column, and inside of it a new document with 1,2,3,4,x... infinitely, how would I be able to search inside the people column for a name without specifying the number in **MongoDB**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/
or you can use MongoTemplate in java and use find method to get list of people in your case.

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how I would be able to find another column part just by that piece of information? I can't really seem to find a good MongoDB documentation with Java, and the ones that are not java are just not suited for it.

Comment: You can use MongoTemplate which has many inbuilt functions which make it easy.

Comment: From what I've seen MongoTemplate is only available through Spring(?), which I don't really know what it is.

Comment: check this out..i think it will help u https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

*What i see is people is a map so you can use*

```
db.collection_name.findOne({"people":{$regex:".*James.*"}});
```

*This will fetch you the value based on name in regex*

Comment: How would I write this in Java? tried a lot of combinations and searching online but I just don't get it. also findOne() doesn't exist in Java, only Find()

Comment: if you are using paid version of studio3t or any other applications they will simply convert your mongod code to respective language

Comment: https://mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-query-document/
use this link

Answer (score 0):

*This is using java*

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("people").regex(".*James.*"));

List<User> userTest = mongoOperation.find(query, User.class);// User.class is the collection-name
System.out.println("query - " + query.toString());

for (User user : userTest) {
    System.out.println("userTest - " + user);
} 
Output
query - Query: { "people" : { "$regex" : ".*James.*"}}, Fields: null, Sort: null
userTest - You will get the collection in array
```

Hope this will works for you.